# Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, video.js

Goodevening, I'm doing a project for university, the poject consist in a video plus a json file. 
While the video player is transmitting the video, it should read a json file and transmit the information contained on the screen.
I'm not a developer and I studied the programming language as a self-taught.

```
var test = document.getElementById("my-video");

var myPlayer = videojs('my-video');

document.onresize = function ()

{

    alert("resize");

};

test.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event )

{

    var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();

    if(whereYouAt < 1) return;


    var name="", image="#", url="#";

    $(function() {


   var contenuto = [];


   $.getJSON('tesi.json', function(data) {

       $.each(data.contenuto, function(i, f) {

          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Modello + "</td>" +

           "<td>" + f.Immagine + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Sito + "</td>" + "</tr>"

           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

     });


   });


});

})
</script>
```

I wrote this code, but when I go to see the video it gives me this error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined.**

I tried to read the forum and look for answers, but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

I would also like to ask you if the **json file parsing** code is correct or if there are errors.

I would be happy for any kind of support.

Comment: Do you have `<script src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.5/video.js'></script>` inside your page code?

Comment: No, i haven't this code in my page. I have only this code for style elements: <link href="video-js-7.6.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">.

Comment: try to add this code to bottom of your page

Comment: I have tried to add the code, but page give me this error: Uncaught TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)

Comment: do you have element with id `'my-video'` on your page?

Comment: I have this code in my html page:                                                                   
<video id='my-video' class='video-js' controls preload='auto' width='1270' height='600' data-setup='{}'>
  <source src='Big Bang Theory.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  <source src='MY_VIDEO.webm' type='video/webm'>
  <p class='vjs-no-js'>
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
  <a href='https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
 </video>